# eclipse An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse

I seem to get this error every time I open up eclipse. I'm using the Juno version with the typical Java developer set up. Any ideas? Thanks!

An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events". java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Is there a stack trace in your workspace's log?  Does it still happen with Juno SR1?  SR2?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems like a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402541), still occurring in Juno SR2.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this on Kepler (installed yesterday, and it is not SR1). Since my message said:

*An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events". 
Java heap space*

I did the obvious - opened the eclipse.ini file and increased the default **vmargs** values to the following:

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
```

These values worked for me and since then the message haven't appeared.

Answer (score 0):

-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
worked for me, I am using eclipse kepler. Please adjust as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

-Xms512m -Xmx512m or -Xms512m -Xmx1024m will work depends upon of your configuration.